# this and _this on a d3 callback in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

I have an element created using d3 as follows:

```
redraw:()->
  #
  points = d3.select(".point").data( the_data )
  points.enter().append("g").classed("point").on("click", @on_click )


on_click:(d,i)-> 
  matrix = this.getScreenCTM()
  # do some stuff
  @popup.show(params)
```

`popup` is a member object with a method `show()`.

the problem is that in the `on_click()` callback I need this to be both the DOM object and the instance so I can reference the data member `popup`.

How should I go about it?

Comment: So you need a single variable to be two different things at once? Have you tried using `d3.select(this)` to get the element?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I need to resolve the ambiguity. I need a way to get the DOM element related to the call to the callback function and I need access to the member object.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to return a function that is closed upon another reference to the original this:

```
on_click: do ->
  self = this
  return (d,i) -> 
    matrix = this.getScreenCTM()
    self.popup.show(params)
```

That way when the function is called by the event handler, `this` is the DOM element, and `self` refers to the original `this` object. Of course, this solution means you lose the shorthand `@` notation.

Comment: This seems right, but for some reason I needed on_click: () -> instead. Any ideas?